# Zombie voice memos living in my iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, voice-memo

Although my voice memos app shows no memos, when I connect my iPhone to my Mac and browse to `On This iPhone > Voice Memos` in iTunes, every voice memo I’ve recorded for the last three years is there (even ones recorded on my previous iPhone).

I tried removing my entire music collection from my iPhone, but they survived. How do I delete them?

Update: Whatever this bug was, it doesn't seem to be present any longer with iOS 8.

Comment: Are they in your music library too? Can't you delete them from there? Can you right click - Info and see where on your hard drive they are stored? Can Spotlight find them?

Comment: They are not on my hard drive anywhere (I've looked thoroughly). They only exist on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a trial of ecamm's [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) from their site -- and perhaps buy it, I've found it very handy. This will allow you to see everything on your phone, copy photos back and forth, and with Admin mode, get into the works.

You should be able to easily delete Voice Memos, those show up on the opening menu.